# Hide the block at the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block that appears after scrolling 1000px on the page

```
const navShareLink = document.getElementById('navShareLink');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if(window.scrollY > 1000 && window.innerWidth > 576) {
    navShareLink.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    navShareLink.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

But when it reaches the end of the page where the footer is, I need it to hide back so that it does not climb into the footer

It's easy to do if the page has the same height, but for me it can be either 2500px or 5000px

Is it possible to somehow count the pixels in reverse order, but not from the beginning of the page, but let's say 300px from the end?

In my example, I try to get the height of the page and subtract 300px from it to set the desired value

```
const navShareLink = document.getElementById('navShareLink');
let pageHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
let endPageHeight = alert(pageHeight - 300);

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if(window.scrollY > 1000 && window.innerWidth > 576) {
    navShareLink.style.display = "block";
  } 
  else if(window.scrollY > endPageHeight && window.innerWidth > 576) {
      navShareLink.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    navShareLink.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

But this line `document.documentElement.scrollHeight;` does not accept a numeric value, but displays this number on the page in a popup tab, and actually nothing works further

Comment: I don't have an answer, but is using absolute pixel values the best approach?  Is there a way you can put this into an element such as <div></div>  in the markup (such as HTML) and then use that element in the javascript ???

Comment: @JosephDoggie can you demonstrate an example? like we have some kind of <div>, and if we get to it then hide the block?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time right now.  But perhaps this can be a starting point toward a solution.  I'd google a version of your above question, and possibly you can find something.